# enums in pandas dataframe, not possible to do groupby on a enumn column?

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, enums

I just learned about enums and thought that they would fit something I'm coding. But when I run this code, I get an error. Am I trying to do something I shouldn't be doing or is this a bug?

When trying to groupby a column with enums, I get this error:
`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'CarBrand' and 'CarBrand'`

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
from enum import Enum

class CarBrand(Enum):
    VOLVO = 'Volvo'
    BMW = 'BMW'

data = {
    'brand': [CarBrand.VOLVO,
              CarBrand.VOLVO, 
              CarBrand.BMW],
    'price': [35000, 
              37000, 
              45000]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
sum_per_brand = df.groupby('brand').sum('price')
print(sum_per_brand)
```

This is the print I was expecting:
brand price
BMW   45000
VOLVO 72000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pd.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) sorts by default. It works if you use `sort=False`:

```py
sum_per_brand = df.groupby('brand', sort=False).sum('price')
```

Alternatively, you could use a datatype which supports sorting (like [CategoricalDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#categoricaldtype)).

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to define ordering in your enum:

```py
from enum import Enum
from functools import total_ordering

import pandas as pd


@total_ordering
class CarBrand(Enum):
    VOLVO = "Volvo"
    BMW = "BMW"

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other.value


data = {
    "brand": [CarBrand.VOLVO, CarBrand.VOLVO, CarBrand.BMW],
    "price": [35000, 37000, 45000],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
sum_per_brand = df.groupby("brand").sum("price")
print(sum_per_brand)
```

Prints:

```
                price
brand                
CarBrand.BMW    45000
CarBrand.VOLVO  72000
```